# AutoCompleteTextView DropDown items in TextInputLayout becomes small in Fragments using OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I'm using `AutoCompleteTextView`, `TextInputLayout`, `ExposedDropdownMenu` from Material design all together and whenever I try to use it inside a `Fragment`, the DropDown items becomes small.

**Layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/responsibility_layout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/type_of_transaction"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_pin_circle_24">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/res_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/your_respon"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Kotlin side (using these codes inside `onViewCreated()` method):**

```
val items = listOf(
        resources.getString(R.string.own_first),
        resources.getString(R.string.own_two))
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext, R.layout.list_drop,
            items)
        (type_of_transaction.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(adapter)

        (type_of_transaction.editText as AutoCompleteTextView).inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL
        type_of_transaction.onFocusChangeListener =
            View.OnFocusChangeListener { _: View?, hasFocus ->
                if (hasFocus) {
                    hideKeyboard(activity)
                }
            }
```

**Proof:**

[image]

The interesting part is that the codes works on `Activity`. Had no clue of why this happening in a `Fragment`.

Any ideas of why this happening? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
 val adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext,...
```

You have to pass `activity` as context instead of `applicationContext`.
The `ApplicationContext` **hasn't** the app theme.

Use:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(),.....
```

With a themed-context

[image]

with an application context:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Good catch. I didn't notice that.